# Delphi - SOAP Request issue with HTTPRIO component

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, delphi-2010

All

Am facing strange issue with SOAP request from delphi,it is working but its not giving expected result.So i have started debugging with SOAP UI and i found below observation.

When am using SOAP UI tool,i tried creating new request and its creating with below header but it is not working as expected(same issue am facing when am sending request from delphi).

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
```

but if i change header to below in SOAP UI request, it is giving expected result.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:acc="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AccountService.DataContracts" xmlns:acc1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AccountService.FaultContracts">
```

How can i change header to HTTPRIO object in delphi 2010?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to modify the `request` in the `OnBeforeExecute` event handler of yout `THTTPRIO` object.

Something like following:

```
procedure TForm1.RIOBeforeExecute(const MethodName: string; SOAPRequest: TStream);
var
  sl : TStringList;
begin
  SOAPRequest.Position := 0;

  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.LoadFromStream(SOAPRequest);
    sl.Text := StringReplace(sl.Text, 'old header text', 'new header text', [rfReplaceAll]);
    SOAPRequest.Size := 0;
    SOAPRequest.Position := 0;
    sl.SaveToStream(SOAPRequest);
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hmmm its changing the text in request but its still not working:(

Comment: We have many functions in webservice,only one purticular function is not working and all other are working perfectly.

Comment: Can you please specify what error you are getting? Is it the same? I have tested this on XE5 and it works. Unfortunately I do not have any copy of Delphi 2010 to test with it...

Comment: Along with the header, you may need to do replacements on namespaces within the body, to match what you've done in the header.  Use this same RIOBeforeExecute handler (above) to dump the request to a file, so you can see what you're sending, then compare to "what works in SoapUI".  Hack as necessary, with further StringReplace. Eventually, you can make the Delphi output look like your SoapUI example.  This shouldn't be necessary, but often is required to make Delphi SOAP work.